# When is a constructor called in nested classes (Java)

Tags: java, class, constructor

I was trying to understand how constructors work and came up with two questions. I have two classes, one for an address and another for a person. the Person class has two Address objects in it. Here is a simplified example of what I'm doing:

```
private class Person{
  private String name;
  private Address unitedStates;
  private Address unitedKingdom;
   Person()
   {
    this.name = "lary"
   }

   Person(String n)
   {
    this.name = n;
    //Can I call Address(string, string) here on unitedStates and unitedKingdom?
   }

                   }//end of person class
private class Address{
  private String street;
  private String country;

  Address()
  {
    this.street = "1 Washington sq";
    this.country = "United States";
  }
  Address(String s, String c)
  {
    this.street = s;
    this.country = c;
  }

}     
}
```

If I leave Person() as is, will it fill the the values for unitedStates and unitedKindom with "1 Washington sq" automatically?

And

Can I pass arguments for the Address object where I left that comment in the example?

Comment: No; it will be null.

Comment: values will be set when contructor called , but in `Person()` , you never call the constructor , so values will be `null` . And you can call the constructor where you left the comment , I tried .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields of an object will always automatically be set with a default value, if not initialized by yourself. The value depends on the data type of the field (see here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). The default value of a field that represents an object is `null`.
Since you didn't initialize the fields `unitedStates` and `unitedKingdom`, their values will be `null`. What you can do is initializing the fields inside the `Person` constructors:

```
Person()
{
    this.name = "lary";
    this.unitedStates = new Address();
    this.unitedKingdom = new Address();
}

Person(String n)
{
    this.name = n;
    this.unitedStates = new Address("myStreet", "myCountry");
    this.unitedKingdom = new Address();
}
```

You could also use one constructor in another with the keyword `this`. Note that I have added a third constructor that is called by the other constructors:

```
Person(String n, Address unitedStates, Address unitedKingdom)
{
    this.name = n;
    this.unitedStates = unitedStates;
    this.unitedKingdom = unitedKingdom;
}

Person(String n)
{
    this(n, new Address("myStreet", "myCountry"), new Address());
}

Person()
{
    this("lary", new Address(), new Address());
}
```

Comment: This helped me understand a lot! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Address field are just initialized as null. you have to assign it an Address instance, in User constructor for example, like

```
unitedStates = new Adress();
```

wich will call the Address's constructor with no parameters.